# Could both an alive and an undead version of a creature exist?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead, soul

Say Bob the fighter dies heroically while fighting some cultists. His companions realise they are outmatched and decide to run. But first, they quickly cut off one of Bob's fingers and take it with them.

After reaching safety, they cast [*resurrection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/resurrection) on the finger, and it grows into a new Bob, assuming [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/100379/44723) answer is correct.

Meanwhile, the cult decide not to waste a perfectly good corpse. So they wait until nightfall and cast [*create undead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-undead) on it.

Is there anything wrong with this scenario? Could Bob the fighter and his companions return to the cultists to be confronted with Bob the undead?

Comment: Schrödingers Bob

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek more like the Bob of Theseus.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### You can't have two Bobs at once, but that's not what you have here

If we look at spells such as *reincarnate*, *raise dead*, *true resurrection*, and *resurrection*, we see that they all mention the soul. However, the *create undead* spell does not impact the soul at all. To quote page 24 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* "Bringing Back the Dead"

> When a creature dies, its soul departs its body, leaves the Material Plane [...] Bringing someone back from the dead means retrieving the soul from that plane and returning it to its body. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> A soul can't be returned to life if it doesn't wish to be. [...]

So when Bob died, his soul had already left; if *create undead* is then cast on his corpse, his soul does *not* go into that undead. Thus, when a spell such as *resurrection* is cast, his soul returns and he can be revived (if he wants to be, that is). Bob only has one *soul*, but Bob's original body and soul are disconnected.

The trick here is that there *aren't* two Bobs. There is Bob's soul, which is now inside a new body (potentially a completely different one, if revived by *reincarnate*) and there is Bob's old *body* which turned into a Ghoul.

Comment: One could liken it to a puppet: if we strung up Bob's old body and made it dance (as macabre as that is), that's not the same as resurrecting it.

Comment: Good answer; and IMO, correct.  Could be improved by citing within 5e what _is_ the animating force for undead, since it is not the souls that were formerly housed in their bodies.

Comment: @Kirt: PHB, page 300: "Like a dome above the other planes, the Positive Plane is the source of radiant energy and the raw life force that suffuses all living beings, from the puny to the sublime. Its dark reflection is the Negative Plane, the source of necrotic energy that destroys the living and animates the undead." So yeah, explicitly fueled by Negative Energy Plane.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Most likely true for ghouls as well as things like skeletons and zombies.  The sentient undead retain their own corrupted souls, and things like crawling claws, for example, are explicitly animated by the evil souls of the once-living body.

Comment: @Kirt In DnD 4e, living creatures had minds, souls, and an animating "animus" that served as their life force. If a creature was turned into a sapient-but-soulless undead (as opposed to a mindless undead like a zombie or skeleton), the undead creature still possessed the animus of the creature that it had the body of, but the lack of a soul allowed the negative energy to twist the mind of the creature towards destruction and evil. As far as I know, that hasn't been contradicted by anything in 5e.

Comment: I don't know that there is a single universal answer because it depends on the nature of the specific undead you're dealing with. Some undead are explicitly the original soul (ghosts are "the soul of a once-living creature"; specters have been "prevented from reaching the afterlife") while some are explicitly *not* the original creature (shadows are stated to try to hunt down their revived living counterpart).  The *create undead* spell may only infuse false life into a corpse and doesn't mess with souls, but that's not the case for every undead.

Comment: @Kirt: It's true for sentient undead too; they all derive their animating force/energy from the Negative Plane. Their will/actions are directed by whatever corrupted soul or soulless intelligence remains in them, but they rely on the Negative Plane in some ill-defined way for their continuing unlife (this connection may only be needed at the moment of creation, not as an ongoing thing, the wording isn't clear, but the Negative Plane is explicitly what animates undead).

Comment: A lot of undead in 5e have explicit mention of having a soul (like a lich) or not having a soul (like a skeleton). Unfortunately, ghoul is not one that mentions it either way.